# Starting an action when View Controller Loads

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

How do I start an action when the view controller loads on screen?

I've managed to do the function I want with an `@IBAction` but I don't want a button press for the action to happen, I want it to start the action when the page loads

any thoughts?

---

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
 var progress: KDCircularProgress!


 @IBOutlet weak var Label1: UILabel!



var LabelText = String()

var scorestart = 1.0
var anglepercent = 3.6


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()




    Label1.text = LabelText

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.22, alpha: 1)

    progress = KDCircularProgress(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
    progress.startAngle = -90
    progress.progressThickness = 0.2
    progress.trackThickness = 0.3
    progress.clockwise = true
    progress.gradientRotateSpeed = 10
    progress.roundedCorners = false
    progress.glowMode = .Forward
    progress.glowAmount = 0.9
    progress.setColors(UIColor.yellowColor())
    progress.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: view.center.y + 25)
    view.addSubview(progress)
}

@IBAction func Animate(sender: AnyObject) {
    progress.angle = Double(scorestart * anglepercent)
    progress.animateFromAngle(0, toAngle: 270, duration: 2) {
        completed in
        if completed {
            print("animation stopped, completed")
        } else {
            print("animation stopped, was interrupted")
        }
```

Comment: Update your question with relevant code showing what you have tried and what issues you are having.

Comment: Call the `@IBAction func Animate...` from `viewDidLoad`. Use `self` as `sender`. And please don't capitalise functions.

Comment: Whatever I seem to be doing it doesn't seem to work

self.animate(self) under the viewDidLoad isnt working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :-

Basic idea here is that whenever your view will load corresponding class will look up to `viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)` function and if it's present in the code it will execute all the code in it.The moment that particular view is about to appear on your UI, your code block in `viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)` will get called.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var progress: KDCircularProgress!


  @IBOutlet weak var Label1: UILabel!



  var LabelText = String()

  var scorestart = 1.0
  var anglepercent = 3.6


  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      Label1.text = LabelText

      view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.22, alpha: 1)


    }


 override func viewWillAppear(animated :Bool) {
      super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        progressActn()
          //Setting up your progress layer
        animateActn()
          //Animating that progress layer
  }



@IBAction func Animate(sender: AnyObject) {
       animateActn()
     }

func animateActn(){
       progress.angle = Double(scorestart * anglepercent)
progress.animateFromAngle(0, toAngle: 270, duration: 2) {
    completed in
    if completed {
        print("animation stopped, completed")
    } else {
        print("animation stopped, was interrupted")
    }
  }

  }
 func progressActn(){

      progress = KDCircularProgress(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
      progress.startAngle = -90
      progress.progressThickness = 0.2
      progress.trackThickness = 0.3
      progress.clockwise = true
      progress.gradientRotateSpeed = 10
      progress.roundedCorners = false
      progress.glowMode = .Forward
      progress.glowAmount = 0.9
      progress.setColors(UIColor.yellowColor())
      progress.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: view.center.y + 25)
      view.addSubview(progress)

 }
}
```